# Health Regen For My Web Game

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an rpg game for web browsers and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to implement a way to Regen Health based on a % of Maximum Health. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This gets the characters Max HP

`getMaxCharHP() <-- Prints out a # like 400`

This Gets The Characters Health Regen Rate Per Minute

`getCharHPR() <-- Prints out a # like 22.31`

How can I write some code to run every minute and restore X% of MaxHP?

Would a cron job be my best approach or does anyone know of a way to do it inside php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing things periodically based on time, a cron job is probably your best option. You can set up a cron job that requests a given URL every so often and then write a PHP page for that URL which does what you want to do.

Comment: would this be the right format for the cron job? The time = `1 0 * * *` and the command to run = `php -f /home/a3343381/cron/health_regen.php`

Comment: is it also possible in the php file i have for the cron job to run to use include or require statements to include/require my config file which has all my database info?

Comment: There's nothing special about invoking the PHP file; it should be able to include whatever you want.

Comment: php can be different depending on how you run it, if you are running an fpm, going through /usr/bin/php might mean you will want to check the php5/cli (command line interface) folder's php.ini and extensions/mods to just ensure everything runs the same, without any surprises.